# ironahk on mac osx; hello world working but hot string is not

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, autohotkey

I installed mono and ironahk on my macbook running osx.

The example.ahk runs fine and gives a 'hello world' message box.

When I try to input a file with a hot string such as:

:*:dog::dalmation@dogpound.edu

it crashes.  What am I doing wrong.  The hot string works OK on windows xp.

Comment: Any luck so far? Let us know what helped and what did not help? We can only learn if you provide feedback!

Comment: Any updates yet? Or is the problem still around, despite the various alternative approaches?

Comment: Apparently there are some issues with IronAHK. see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1832937 I just wanted to install this on my Ubuntu on VMware, but stopped when I read this!

Answer (score 0):

Your hotstring:

```
:*:dog::dalmation@dogpound.edu
```

runs fine on AutoHotKey on Windows 7x64. It 'could' be that IronAhk crashes because it loops due to the fact that the string "dog" is part of the output string "dalmation@DOGpound.edu". In other words the behaviour of IronAhk 'might' be different in that it wants to output:

```
dalmation@dalmation@dalmation@dalmation@dalmation@dogpound.edupound.edupound.edupound.edupound.edu
```

, constantly replacing "dog" inside the string. I don't know if IronAhk has been written from scratch or is just a modified version of Ahk, compiled to the various platforms.

In AutoHotKey the string `dog` would not trigger, because it only acts on `dog` when it is a separate word (not inside a string, unless you use the :?*:).

Unfortunately, IronAHK has no documentation on hotstrings yet.

1st suggestion: first try to launch the output string with a different trigger word.

```
:*:dpe::dalmation@dogpound.edu
```

2nd suggestion: Use send instead

```
:*:dpe::Send, dalmation@dogpound.edu
```

3rd suggestion: Use send in a multi-line script

```
:*:dpe::
    Send, dalmation@dogpound.edu
Return
```

Last but not least, using a dictionary word to trigger a hotstring can lead to frustration when writing. That is why most of my trigger words end with a unique character <kbd>\</kbd> or <kbd>=</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>.</kbd>.

In your case that would be :*:dog::. The <kbd>\</kbd> is located close to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, which makes it easy.

I actually have categories of hotstrings all with a unique end character:
This way I can use the same trigger strings in different languages. I sometimes even use it to "translate" difficult to write words.

<kbd>\</kbd> is for Dutch,
<kbd>=</kbd> is for English,
<kbd>]</kbd> is for generic words (e.g. AutoHotKey).
<kbd>.</kbd> is to intersperse an abbreviation with the right dots.

This way I can type:
`eg.` and turn it into `e.g.`
`eg=` and turn it into `for example`
`eg\` and turn it into `even geduld`.